# Limiting provider scope to component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service, 'fileService"
Currently injected at root, but I want it limited to one component, 'fileComponent'.
If i do this:
@Injectable({
providedIn: FileComponent
})

and list FileSerive as a provider the in the component:
@Component({
selector: 'something',
templateUrl: 'something',
providers: [FileService]
})

I get an error saying "FileService" cannot be accessed before instantiation.
Thought?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting that error because there is circular dependency between component and service.

You shouldn't be putting Angular component to `providedIn` property of `@Injectable` decorator.

All you need to do in order to limit provider scope to component is to add it to `providers` array of that component:

```
@Component({
  /* . . . */
  providers: [FileService]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

put it in the component providers:

```
@Component({
  //...
  providers: [FileService]
})
export class MyComponent {
}
```